# Can a diamond Contract be cloned?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin-contracts, clone

```
 Error: invalid address or ENS name (argument="name", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0)
```

So this is the error that occured. I am trying to implement diamond contract in a project.

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/Clones.sol";

function createVault(VaultDetails memory _VAULT_DETAILS, address[] memory _WHITELISTED_ASSETS,  Whitelisted[] memory _WHITELISTED_DETAILS, address _VAULT) public returns (address vault) {
        console.log("Creating vault");
    
    if (validVault[_VAULT] == true){
        vault = Clones.clone(VAULT);
        _VAULT_DETAILS.ORACLE_CONTRACT = ORACLE;
        IVault(vault).initialize(_VAULT_DETAILS, _WHITELISTED_ASSETS, _WHITELISTED_DETAILS);
        vaults.push(address(vault));
    }
}
```

All the arguments values are correctly inputed.In a normal contract, the Vault is created but it gives error in the diamond implementation.
Does Diamond support OpenZepplin clones ?

The initialize code is :

```
function initialize(
    VaultDetails memory _VAULT_DETAILS,
    address[] memory _WHITELISTED_ASSETS,
    Whitelisted[] memory _WHITELISTED_DETAILS
) external {
    VAULT_DETAILS = _VAULT_DETAILS;
    WHITELISTED_ASSETS = _WHITELISTED_ASSETS;

    uint length = _WHITELISTED_ASSETS.length;
    uint32 max_exposure;
    for (uint i = 0; i < _WHITELISTED_ASSETS.length; i++) {
        WHITELISTED_DETAILS[_WHITELISTED_DETAILS[i].collection] = _WHITELISTED_DETAILS[i];
        idx[_WHITELISTED_DETAILS[i].collection] = i;

        if (_WHITELISTED_DETAILS[i].MAX_EXPOSURE > max_exposure) {
            MAIN_ASSET = _WHITELISTED_ASSETS[i];
            max_exposure = _WHITELISTED_DETAILS[i].MAX_EXPOSURE;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error is in the `initialize()`, can you share the initialization code in the solidity Vault?, and the arguments?

Comment: The initialize function is added as requested.

Comment: could you provide also the args you use? I think there is the problem as the error is a ethers.js one, ethers.js can not read the args

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem had occured because of a missing args..